# How to disable Ctrl + Tab in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I usually cycle between tabs (e.g. in Chrome, Visual Studio Code, etc.) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

But in my Ubuntu 20.04 this key combination displays this instead:

[image: Ctrl+Tab shows this (while holding the Ctrl key)]

Is it possible to disable this and let individual application decides how to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

I tried to go to **Settings** → **Keyboard Shortcuts**, but there is no item in the list that uses Ctrl+Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is by default assigned to the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. That is a shortcut key allowing keyboard access to Gnome Shell components.

First try resetting the keybinding to default:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward
```

If that does not work, you could disable the keybindings with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward "['']"
```